# Please re(run) biber

Tags: biblatex, biber, zotero

I think I've read all posts concerning this issue and a solution might have been provided but I don't understand it.

Here is the full story.

I export my bibliography file from Zotero (I tried everything BibTex, BibLaTex, UTF-8 and Western, all possible combinations).

I work in Texniccenter editor.

I would like to use biblatex (the example is not full, it's a thesis normally, so too long).

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibli}
\title{YYY}
\author{\textsc{ZZZ}}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}
\mainmatter
\part{State of the art}
\chapter{blabla}
L'intérêt pour l'activité d'abattage a été étudié à plusieurs reprises en sciences sociales. Toutefois, la condition animale en elle-même y est très peu abordée, sans doute parce que les acteurs de terrain eux-mêmes la considère comme un non-sujet \cite{muller_a_2008}.
\printbibliography
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliographie}
\end{document}
```

Here is a part of my bibliography file:

```
@book{muller_a_2008,
    address = {Paris; Versailles},
    title = {{\'A} l'abattoir: travail et relations professionnelles face au risque sanitaire},
    isbn = {978-2-7351-1170-1 978-2-7592-0051-1},
    shorttitle = {{\'A} l'abattoir},
    language = {French},
    publisher = {{\'E}ditions de la Maison des sciences de l'homme ; {\'E}ditions Quae},
    author = {Muller, S{\'e}verin},
    year = {2008},
    note = {OCLC: 262718567}
}
```

Probably the answer is simple, but I am quite new, and yes, I really read a lot of documentation, without finding anything useful.

I also tried to change the settings of output profile (use `biber` instead of `bibtex`) but it did not work.

Problem might come from Zotero? If so how to know where cause my file is super long?...

Comment: if latex tells you to rerun biber, that means that you either didn't run biber at all (but e.g bibtex instead), or that you did run biber but that there was an error. Find the .blg-file in your folder, open it in your editor and check what it says.

Comment: Note that if you are a new user texniccenter might not be a good editor to use: (1) it does not seem to have been updated since 2014, (2) it does not come with its own PDF viewer, and thus jumping back and forth between texniccenter and he PDF is something you have to set up manually. Might be worth checking texmaker or texstudio (they look similar but texstudio has more features). AFAIR both texmaker and texstudio have build in configurations to switch to biber.

Comment: [0] Config.pm:304> INFO - This is Biber 2.14
[0] Config.pm:307> INFO - Logfile is 'These.blg'
[105] biber-MSWIN64:322> INFO - === 
[129] Biber.pm:415> INFO - Reading 'These.bcf'
[279] Biber.pm:943> INFO - Found 31 citekeys in bib section 0
[313] Biber.pm:4256> INFO - Processing section 0
[314] Utils.pm:75> INFO - Globbing data source 'bibli'
[340] Utils.pm:91> INFO - Globbed data source 'bibli' to bibli
[381] Biber.pm:4455> INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'bibli' for section 0
[1001] Utils.pm:320> ERROR - Cannot find 'bibli'!
[1002] Biber.pm:132> INFO - ERRORS: 1

Comment: Try `\addbibresource{bibli.bib}` (_with_ the `.bib` extension).

Comment: THANKS! I feel stupid now...

Comment: @PaulGaborit Do you want to type up an answer here, or do we close this as 'not interesting to the general public'?

Comment: There is a sort-of duplicate at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140458/35864, where the `.bib` file extension is also missing, but there are some other things wrong there as well, so the answer is a bit longer and mentions unrelated things.

Comment: You can replace `\printbibliography
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliographie}` with `\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]`. This is not only shorter, but will also work properly in case your bibliography has several pages. Note that the `isbn` field should only contain one ISBN, not several. Note further that one of the strengths of Biber is that it can deal with UTF-8 input, so you need not encode non-ASCII chars with macros (you can say `Á` instead of `{\'A}`). ...

Comment: ...  Nowadays it is preferable to use UTF-8 instead of `latin1`, but I think that Texniccenter still uses `latin1` as default: One reason more to switch to a different editor.

Comment: @PaulGaborit Thanks. Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

The Biber error message is clear: `ERROR - Cannot find 'bibli'!`

Use `\addbibresource{bibli.bib}` (with the `.bib` extension) instead of `\addbibresource{bibli}`.